# How to get a field by index in template?

Tags: go, go-templates

I send a slice of `articles` into template. Each `article`struct is like:

```
type Article struct {
    ID        uint32        `db:"id" bson:"id,omitempty"` 
    Content   string        `db:"content" bson:"content"`
    Author    string        `db:"author" bson:"author"`
    ... 
}
```

I can loop over `articles` slice in a `{{range $n := articles}}` and get each `{{$n.Content}}` but what I want is to have only the first one (outside the range loop) to use in headline. 
What I tried is:

```
{{index .articles.Content 0}}
```

But  I get:

> Template File Error: template: articles_list.tmpl:14:33: executing
>   "content" at <.articles.Content>: can't evaluate field Content in type
>   interface {}

If I just invoke

```
{{index .articles 0}}
```

It shows the whole article[0] object.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The index function access the nth element of the specified array, so writing

`{{ index .articles.Content 0 }}`

is essentially trying to write `articles.Content[0]`

You would want something akin to

`{{ with $n := index .articles 0 }}{{ $n.Content }}{{ end }}`

Comment: Yep, that solved the problem. Though I wished there was a less verbose way to do so...

Answer (score 5):

A more concise way is:

```
{{(index .articles.Content 0).Content }}
```

Which would be the equivalent of `articles[0].Content`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{(index .articles 0).Content}}
```